# Date format English / French

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I have this kinf of date format :

```
Mon, Nov 19, 2018
```

And I want it in a french short date format (DD/MM/YYY)
But i can't resolve it with basic date format with excel.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Is the date really like this: "Mon, Nov 19, 2018" or is it something similar in french?

Comment: And do you really want it like : "DD/MM/YYY" or "DD/MM/YYYY"?

Comment: The first thing to check is if your data actually in date format (`ddd, mmm dd, yyyy`) and let us know

Comment: The dates are really like this, but excel see it like a "text" format. That's why it's hard to change the format, it doesn't understand that it's a date. So, my aim problem is not how about the final format will be, but just that excel recognise it like a date...

Comment: I edited what I see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MATCH to return the correct month:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,3)),{"Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"},0),MID(A1,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","}}}",2))+1,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, hard to translate in french Excel

Comment: Open the VBE and in the immediate window put: `Activesheet.RAnge("B2").Formula = "=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(TRIM(MID(A1,FIND("" "",A1)+1,3)),{""Jan"",""Feb"",""Mar"",""Apr"",""May"",""Jun"",""Jul"",""Aug"",""Sep"",""Oct"",""Nov"",""Dec""},0),MID(A1,FIND(""}}}"",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"" "",""}}}"",2))+1,2))"` and hit enter.  It will put the formula in B1 of the activesheet and make the translation.

Comment: Yes it will unless you have your date in A1.  But it should give you the french version of the formula.  The formula points to a1.

Comment: Then I do not know what to say, it works for me.  Either you did not give all the information or the information you gave is in error.

Comment: It works !! Thank you very much ! And thank you for the VBA tips too

Answer (score 0):

To convert your text into a date, you can use this formula (assuming the date in text format is in cell C15):

```
=DATE(RIGHT(C15,4),IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Jan"),01,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Feb"),02,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Mar"),03,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Apr"),04,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"May"),05,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Jun"),06,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Jul"),07,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Aug"),08,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Sep"),09,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Oct"),10,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Nov"),11,IF(EXACT(MID(C15,6,3),"Dec"),12)))))))))))),MID(C15,10,2))
```

Then you get an Excel date that is easier to work with.